# Is there any networking framework based on C?

Tags: c, networking, open-source

I know there are EventMachine and Twist， they are pretty good! but is there any networking framework based on C ?

Comment: What kind of features would you expect a "networking framework" to have? It's not a very clear term, at least not to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I haven't misread your question, I believe [**libevent**](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) should fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

Try [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/). Liberal license. Quick/Easy to learn

Answer (score 0):

It is not C, but if you can use C++, then I would recommend [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview.html).